# Writing reusable CloudFormation snippets with AWS::Include and Nested Stacks

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I have been using [nested stacks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-stack.html) in `CloudFormation` for several months and they are very useful.  So I thought I should spend sometime to make each nested stack reusable to other teams in the org.

I saw the use case of [AWS::Include](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/create-reusable-transform-function-snippets-and-add-to-your-template-with-aws-include-transform.html) in several places like [here](https://thomasvachon.com/articles/making-modular-cloudformation-with-includes/) and [here](https://medium.com/@antonf_70246/aws-cloudformation-transforms-and-multiple-mappings-6475b332da3c) and it makes good sense to me.

One approach I have in mind is one **snippet** for each resource, like an `AWS::EC2::Subnet` or `AWS::EC2::InternetGateway` which can be included *zero or more times* into a `vpc.json` template, which itself can be used as a nested stack in a larger application.

The snippet does not take any parameters, but can reference a parameter that exists in the parent template.

At first glance this doesn't seem enough to me.  Consider this example:

```
"PublicSubnet": {
  "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
  "Properties": {
    "VpcId": {"Ref": "VPC"},
    "AvailabilityZone": {
       "Fn::Select" : [ "0", { "Fn::GetAZs" : {"Ref": "AWS::Region"} }]
    },
    "CidrBlock": {
      "Fn::FindInMap": ["AZSubnetMap", {
         "Fn::Select" : [ "0", { "Fn::GetAZs" : {"Ref": "AWS::Region"} }]},
         "PublicSubnet"]},
    "MapPublicIpOnLaunch": "true",
    "Tags": [..]
  }
}
```

How can I avoid hard coding that `"0"` for the AZ in a Subnet snippet for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, AWS doesn't provide a way to dynamically update the template as per the requirement.

I have solved a similar problem using [Mustache Templates](https://mustache.github.io/) using Java Library [Handle Bars](https://github.com/jknack/handlebars.java). Using this library you can generate template on the fly based on the requirements.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I have thought about this as well, but I don't want to do any programmatic solution just yet.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use two AWS::Include files located in:

- s3://yourname/PublicSubnetA.yaml
- s3://yourname/PublicSubnetB.yaml

And call them from your MAIN Template:

```
Fn::Transform:        
    Name: AWS::Include
    Parameters:
      Location : "s3://yourname/PublicSubnetA.yaml"   


 Fn::Transform:        
    Name: AWS::Include
    Parameters:
      Location : "s3://yourname/PublicSubnetB.yaml"
```

I 'am trying to find way to send additional parameters or override parameter to AWS::include, as you see it has 
***Parameters:
      Location:***

Why ti's not understanding more parameters and not just Location, I would be glad to have something like this:

```
 Fn::Transform:        
    Name: AWS::Include
    Parameters:
      MySubnetIndex: 0
      Location : "s3://yourname/PublicSubnetB.yaml"
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried this way to send additional parameters:

```
Fn::Transform:        
    Name: AWS::Include
    Parameters:
       Location : "s3://my.test/create-ec2.yaml"   
       EC2Size :
         Type:  String
         Default: "t2.micro"
```

And got interesting error:

**The value of parameter EC2Size under transform Include must resolve to a string, number, boolean or a list of any of these**

Looks like it understand what this is additional parameters, probably it need to be configured little bit different. I was not able to find way to fix this error yet.

Comment: Do you have any progress on that?